# GDAL with PostgreSql LIST_ALL_TABLES fails?

Tags: gdal

I have compiled GDAL 2.0.0 and am accessing a PG database. I note that the online documentation has two options available with the word "TABLES" in it. I think the logic in the code isn't handling the second syntax correctly.

(1) TABLES=string: Restricted set of tables to list (comma separated).

(2) LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES/NO: This may be "YES" to force all tables,
   including non-spatial ones, to be listed.

When I use a connect string like this:

PG:dbname='OpenGIS' host='xxxx' port='5432' user='xxxx' password='xxxx' active_schema=public schemas=public,tiger LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES

I get an error (my own handler in CPP program):

[PQconnectdb failed. missing "=" after "LIST_ALL_" in connection info string]

What I see in ogrpgdatasource.cpp at line 440 is some code starting like this:

```
pszTableStart = strstr(pszConnectionName, "tables=");
if (pszTableStart == NULL)
    pszTableStart = strstr(pszConnectionName, "TABLES=");
```

This code strips out the TABLES=... options for some reason, but the logic seems to ignore the other possibility of LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES.

I tried using mixed case options but that gives another error:

[invalid connection option "LIST_all_TabLeS"]

I've tried single quotes, double quotes etc but the result is the same.

What I am suspecting is that the parser is pretty simple and is not quite handling this right.

There may be a similar issue in SpatiaLite driver ? - I am working on that next.

I am working on Windows 10 and VS 2013 and don't have a project to build and test with.

Does anybody have a similar issue or am just using the wrong syntax?

Comment: You are probably using wrong syntax. With ogrinfo you would use the option as `-oo LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES`. Make a test with ogrinfo. If you can see that open options work you know you did it wrong.

Comment: Thanks user30184, this pointed me in the right direction, it works as you described. The cause of my problem was that in the call to open the dataset I put the options as part of the pszDataSource when they should have been in the papszOpenOptions - GDALOpenEx( pszDataSource, GDAL_OF_READONLY | GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, papszOpenOptions, NULL );